# How to extract data from byte array ([B cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte)

Tags: java, java-8

I have tried to extract data from byte array my input data as like `msg=byte[7064],` so I need to extract the data from byte[], below code I tried

> byte[] but=new byte [(byte)msg];

When I tried to run it was throwing Classcast exception , I tried my luck but am not able to find any solution , Any help will be appreciate

After converting byte I need to convert as string data, output like `name=walterwhite, job=teacher`

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your message (msg). So that the big picture can be captured.

Comment: looks like `msg` is a `String`, thus `msg.getBytes()`?

Comment: What is the type of `msg`? Is it array of `byte`s? Then it can't be cast to a byte - thats what you're trying to do here: `new byte [(byte)msg]`

Comment: `String output = new String(msg, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // UTF_8`

Comment: @Eugene msg is not a string it's a generic message from jms

Comment: it still has a certain _type_, doesn't it?

Comment: @Eugene no!!  msg.payload =byte[]

Comment: so if `msg.payload` _is_ a `byte array`, why are you trying to convert it via a cast? and, of course, if `msg.payload` _has_ a field - it is a _certain_ type/object. there is something very wrong in your understanding, it seems.

Comment: @Eugene yeah I accept it!! Because msg.payload is spring message so for that I was thinking like convert into byte[] and then I will extract the data !!

Comment: @Eugene when  I tried to convert msg.payload byte [] to string it was indicating error..!!  So I thought like I need to convert into java byte []

Comment: @JoopEggen why do you add a comment `// UTF_8` to a statement that clearly uses `ISO_8859_1`?

Comment: @Holger The encoding is unclear; going first with ISO-8859-1 will deliver something, UTF-8 might be better. Important is  that the OP _should_ consider which encoding is used. Made my comment as the discussion/solutions went in the other direction (getBytes). The OP seems to agree.

Answer (score 1):

Below one is correct..

> String converted=new String ((byte[])msg,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
>   );

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] bytes = "hello world".getBytes();
    String s = new String(bytes);

    System.out.println("s = " + s);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.